# Stacked and nested if else statements no moving to next if

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, nested

I have been searching Stacked/Nested if else statements, elif's don't seem to work for what I need.
The Aim is to print all even, square numbers, and cube numbers as well as highlight which ones are both square and Cube.
This is the code i have:

```
import math
rn = 0
for n in range(1,100,1):
    if rn is 0:
        if n%2 is 0:
            print(n, " is an even number")           
        else:
            rn = 1         
        if math.sqrt(n) is int:
            print(n, " is a square number")
            if n**(1/3) is int:
                print(n, " is a Cube number too")
                continue
            else:
                print(n, "is only a square number")
                continue

        else:
            rn = 1
    if rn is 1:
        if n**(1/3) is int:
            print(n, " is a Cube only number")
        else:
            rn = 0
            continue
```

The code is not moving on to the next if statements, before incrementing n.

output:

```
   2  is an even number
   4  is an even number
   6  is an even number
```

Is there another way to continue or break but staying in the same loop?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `if n%2 is 0:
            print(n, " is an even number")           
        else:
            rn = 1         
        if math.sqrt(d) is int:` this piece of code is causing it. This is because after you have called else, the next if statement will never be executed. You're first telling the computer that `if n%2 is 0:` to do something. Afterwards you tell it that if it isn't, do something else. Then it gets another if, but it has already returned the answer in else.

Comment: What is the intended purpose of `if math.sqrt(d) is int:`? Also, you should be using `==` to test for equality, not `is`, but I'm not sure what that line is supposed to check. You want to check for a whole number?

Comment: @roganjosh, yes i am checking for a whole, number, when I searched on how to do this statement it mentioned, that they format i used was best practice.

Comment: @chromaerror I understand that, hence why i am asking for a solution to resolve the issue. do you have one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import math
rn = 0
d=0.
for n in range(1,100,1):
    if rn is 0:
        if n%2 is 0:
            print(n, " is an even number")
        else:
            rn = 1
        if math.sqrt(d).is_integer():
            print(n, " is a square number")
            if float(n**(1-3)).is_integer():
                print(n, " is a Cube number too")
                continue
            else:
                print(n, "is only a square number")
                continue

        else:
            rn = 1
    if rn is 1:
        if n**(1-3) is int:
            print(n, " is a Cube only number")
        else:
            rn = 0
            continue
```

This will work, using `float.is_integer()`, the problem before was that `is int` was returning `False` for any input. Also note that this will give for all numbers from 1 to 100 `>> {} is a square number` because you are doing `math.sqrt(d)` and `d` is `0` and so the square root is always integer `0`

Comment: `n**(1-3)` is the same as `n**(-2)`, so there is no cube root there

Comment: @AzatIbrakov, there is a lot wrong with his code, in both if statement logic and variable usage and syntax. But his question was: why aren't the rest of the if- statements after `if n%2 is 0:` not working. I answered because his if statements make no sense, the rest he can figure out on his own. I am not here to finish his homework. Also I think he meant to write `n**(1/3)` but mistakenly wrote `-` instead of `/`.

Comment: yeah there was some typo's and remenants of previous attempts to debug, still there, which was adding to errors, d has been removed and set, back to n, and - has been replaced by /
and while this code is now mostly functional it will not return, 64 as a cube number but square only ??

Comment: @StefanPAuckland because `float(64**(1/3))` prints `3.9999999999999996`, it's not a problem with the algorithm logic but mostly computer precision and limitations. try to add a filter let's say `tol = 1e-5` and use `if math.floor(n**(1-3) - tol) != math.floor floor(n**(1-3) + tol):` This means that anything from 3.999991 to 4.00002 will count as 4 or integer. Alternatively with lower `tol` you can tighten your interval.

Comment: Thanks Hadi, that solves that issue perfectly, all the ifs, and elses appear to function fine :) Much appreciated 
(Also FYI I'm just a wanting to learn for fun, this it not homework.)

Comment: @StefanPAuckland no worries mate, homework or not I was trying to make Azat understand that I am not here to solve it for you directly but guide you, first you try and when you fail I can show you. But not just dump a solved solution on you. Keep trying, good job.